# ImportError: No module named 'boto3': Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, boto3, bitbucket-pipelines

I am writing a BitBucket Pipelines script. I am trying to install `boto3` on my Ubuntu 14.04 Docker VM to be imported by Python 3.5. However, when I try to `import boto3` I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'boto3'
```

My `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` looks like this:

```
image: me/company

pipelines:
 branches:
   master:
     - step:
         script:
           - npm install
           - npm run build
           - python get-pip.py
           - pip install boto3
           - python3.5 s3_upload.py io-master.company.co.uk dist io-master
```

There are loads of posts, both on StackOverflow and various other forums around, but none of them solve the problem.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `pip3 install boto3`??

Comment: Have you tried: import botocore ?

Comment: @AChampion thanks, but that doesn't work

Comment: No @ApoorvKansal. I shall try that right now

Comment: Docker container doesn't deal with pypi repo directly. Skim through the document to fix them. 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/docker-explained-how-to-containerize-python-web-applications

Comment: That doesn't help I'm afraid @mootmoot. I have had Python3.5 running happily already, but now it is complaining about this one particular import.

Comment: Package works differently inside docker. If you still can't run `pip install boto3` ,  try convert this command to your pipelines script `python3.5 -m pip install boto3`.

Comment: I am now using `pip install boto3`, and then when I run `python3.5`, I still can't import boto3

Comment: Does it help when you use `pip3 install boto3` ?

Answer (score 1):

Hit the same problem

```
vagrant@saltmaster:~$ ./run.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run.py", line 2, in <module>
    import boto3
ImportError: No module named 'boto3'
vagrant@saltmaster:~$

vagrant@saltmaster:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

The problem see to be that there is not python3-boto3 module in ubuntu 14.04

only python3-botocore

Comment: When you do "pip3 install boto3" , pip3 wants to remove urllib3 but cannot do as it is apt managed. When removing python3-urllib3 by apt, it wants to remove ubuntu-desktop, the life, the universe and everything. Unfortunately botocore is not the same as boto3 .